# Start programming to Android

Tags: android, programming-languages

I know there is a dedicated area for Android issues, **BUT** I just want to know if there's an option to program to Android in C or in Java, and what will be the best language to write apps for Android.

This info you can't find in the Android area...

Thanks !!

Comment: Sigh, can you not at least google the question? I mean, Java is pretty much the mainstream language for Android. Its what the SDK uses. Google Android SDK and you find your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Java to program Android. It says it in the documentation for development for Android.

You can also use the NDK but don't start with that.

Answer (score 3):

Android practically is java.
Just read some how to start tutorials and you will see theres not much difference to conventional java applications.
It is Java with some platform dependent features.

SDK:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

DevGuides:
http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Answer (score 2):

The Android API is in Java. You can find the developer guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html).

For performance-critical code, you can use the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html).

Comment: Will it be difficult to program to Android ?

Comment: It all depends on your level of programming experience. I wouldn't say it's any more or less difficult than coding for another OS.

Answer (score 2):

Android's comprehensive java SDK makes it a lot easier to write apps in Java.  You should check out the [getting started](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) page on their developer site.

Comment: Will it be easy to write to Android in Java ? 
Is there a working future in the industry for Android programmers ?

Comment: Of course.  Android is the fastest-growing mobile platform around right now.  Java is also a lot easier to program in than C.

Comment: Not 100% sure I agree with that. Oh well, who am I kidding. I LIKE C better... but Java was easier to learn.

Comment: So you say there are many opening positions for talented Android developers ?

Comment: @Maximus, trust me, I like C a lot better too.  Its kinda hard to recommend it to a newbie android developer though.  @Master C, I can't say how many positions there are, I don't know, but I do know it's very easy to sell your own apps with android.

Answer (score 2):

The best? Java.
You can also write in C/C++ with the NDK.
And you can also write with Python or, say, Scala, but is not easy at all.

Java is the best because the API is Java, so all the documentation is in Java. Equally important, Google's ADT plugin to program Android in Eclipse is super easy, so you are going to work with an IDE, no need to advanced text editors and so.

Comment: Nothing at all! But if someone asks how to start programming in Android, i (perhaps wrongly) belive it should start with a bloated but in a way simpler IDE, where you create a project and there you go, you have an Activity and everything set.

Comment: Also in defense if Eclipse, I learned Java specifically to develop for Android, so having the IDE nudge me along the way when I was doing something wrong (scope issues, etc) has been very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Android applications are java based. (although I heard new NDK support development of full application in C).

It is possible to develop some libraries in c/c++ and load them to your application using JNI, which is also a Java feature. Start from here: http://developer.android.com/index.html I know it seems to general, but the official site is a great place to start from.

Comment: So with NDK I can write for Android in C language ?

Comment: C and C++. you will still need to wrap it with java probably, but yes.